# What happens when new items are placed in composer.json file within Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am having a hard time thoroughly understanding how the composer.json file works within a Laravel application.  I can build Laravel projects, but I am self-taught and have never fully understand what happens in the composer.json file.

For example, I have a current project that has the following within composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
```

I attempted doing composer require livewire/livewire, but then realized livewire required a newer version of php.  I am using XAMPP 3.2.4 and the php version is 7.2.28.  So, I backed up my files from my htdocs and database and am downloading a newer version of XAMPP.

I assume I would then change my composer.json file to:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
```

But, I cannot understand what is really happening here.  Is this just saying that the server needs to have php version 7.4 or higher on it for the application to work?  Or is it placing new files in the vendor directory?  Do I need to delete any files out of the vendor directory?

Comment: Your current php version is **7.2.28** and you changes on `composer.json` to **"php": "^7.4"**, that means, you cant use below 7.4 version.

Comment: Just for completeness: this is in no way related to Laravel itself. Composer does not know anything about the underlying application, besides the requirements you state in your `composer.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

composer is the php packages and dependency manager. to not copy past all what you need for your project you use composer.
when you write a package name in the composer.json require section then composer will fetch it from his sources (The main source of composer is packagist).

About the vendor directory, if you delete it your application will simply don't work, if you are storing the app somewhere (in a repo for example), you provide only the composer.json and then you will have the same vendor with taping 'Composer install'

Good luck